# How to change response and content-length in uwsgi middleware?

Tags: python, wsgi, werkzeug

I'm trying to write a middleware which replaces some data in the response thus changing the content length. For our development environment we want to simulate the behaviour of SSI includes of the actual webserver like Nginx or Apache for some static files which are not served through the application. We're using the included development server of werkzeug.

Here is what i have so far:

```
class ModifyBodyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environment, start_response):
        def my_start_response(status, headers, exc_info=None):
            # change content-length somehow
            start_response(status, headers, exc_info)

        body = self.app(environment, my_start_response)
        body = do_modifications(body)

        return body
```

For simplification just assume `do_modifications` does replace the whole content with `foobar`. I need the actual body to modify it but i also need to set the new content-length header somehow.

Thanks
Goir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a solution, instead of adding another Middleware I just overwrite the SharedDataMiddleware and modify the file when its read.

EDIT: Added recursive calls to include file in included files.
EDIT2: added support for #echo SSI

```
        class SharedDataSSIMiddleware(SharedDataMiddleware):
    """ Replace SSI includes with the real files on request
    """
    ssi_incl_expr = re.compile(r'<!-- *# *include *(virtual|file)=[\'\"]([^\'"]+)[\'\"] *-->')
    ssi_echo_expr = re.compile(r'<!-- *# *echo *encoding=[\'\"]([^\'"]+)[\'\"] *var=[\'\"]([^\'"]+)[\'\"] *-->')

    def __init__(self, app, exports, disallow=None, cache=True, cache_timeout=60 * 60 * 12, fallback_mimetype='text/plain'):
        super(SharedDataSSIMiddleware, self).__init__(app, exports, disallow, cache, cache_timeout, fallback_mimetype)

        self.environment = None

    def get_included_content(self, path_info, path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path_info, path)
        with open(full_path) as fp:
            data = fp.read()
            return self._ssi_include(full_path, data)

    def _get_ssi_echo_value(self, encoding, var_name):
        return self.environment.get(var_name)

    def _ssi_include(self, filename, content):
        content = re.sub(
            self.ssi_incl_expr,
            lambda x: self.get_included_content(os.path.dirname(filename), x.groups()[1]),
            content
        )
        content = re.sub(
            self.ssi_echo_expr,
            lambda x: self._get_ssi_echo_value(*x.groups()),
            content
        )
        return content

    def _opener(self, filename):
        file = cStringIO.StringIO()
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            content = fp.read()
            content = self._ssi_include(filename, content)
            file.write(content)
            file.flush()
            size = file.tell()
        file.reset()

        return lambda: (file, datetime.utcnow(), size)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        self.environment = environ
        response = super(SharedDataSSIMiddleware, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
        self.environment = None
        return response
```

This reads the actual file, modifies it and returns a StringIO object with the modified data instead of the actual file.
Don't use `static_files` parameter in `run_simple` of werkzeug, this will just add the default SharedDataMiddleware we don't want here.

just wrap your app with the Middleware above:

```
app = SharedDataSSIMiddleware(app, exports={'/foo': 'path'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Where in the content do you want to make the modifications? Should modifications only be done for certain response content types?

This sort of thing can get complicated. In the simplest case you would delay calling the server `start_response()` in your middleware until you have buffered up the complete response in memory so you can modify it and calculate the new response header for content length. This though will cause problems if you are returning very large responses, or streaming responses.

If dealing only with HTML and need to make a change in the `<head>` only, then you can use a mechanism which buffers, but only buffers until it sees `<body>`, or as failsafe, a certain number of bytes have been buffered. If you expect to insert anything just before `</body>` then you can't avoid buffering everything, which is typically bad.

The big question is what are you actually trying to do this for. If this was known then it may be possible to provide a better answer or guide you in a different direction as to what to do.

---

UPDATE 1

FWIW. If you were using mod_wsgi-express, all you would need to do is add the additional `--include-file` option with argument of `ssi.conf` and in the `ssi.conf` configuration file snippet add:

```
LoadModule filter_module ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_filter.so
LoadModule include_module ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_include.so

<Location />
Options +Includes
AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/html
</Location>
```

If the response content type was `text/html` it would then be passed through the Apache `INCLUDES` filter and expanded appropriately.

Thus you could make use of:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html

If the intent is to eventually target SSI mechanisms of Apache in production, then this would give you a more reliable result as mod_wsgi-express is still using Apache to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is simulate a webservers SSI behaviour (including files) in our development environement for static javascript files to avoid setting up a webserver for development and keep it simple. Normally i would use templates and handle this when the template gets rendered but those files should not run through the actual app. In a production environment they are directly handled by the webserver without even hitting the actual app. The app doesnt have url rules or even know these files exist.

Comment: If you are using Apache as the server, what is the configuration you are using for doing SSI? If you were to use mod_wsgi-express (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) for development then it may not be too hard to coax it into doing SSI as it uses Apache under the covers without you needing to know and the generated configuration it uses can be augmented to do extra stuff.

Comment: I want to keep the setup for the development environment as easy and lightweigt as possible. I've found a solution to the problem. Will update it in a second with #echo support.

Comment: I would suggest that you might be jumping to the conclusion that because mod_wsgi and Apache is involved it isn't light weight. The whole point of mod_wsgi-express is that it is a stripped down and properly tuned combination of Apache and mod_wsgi where you don't have to fiddle around with Apache configurations, this SSI case being an exception as SSI is very rarely used these days. So any idea that it is bloated would be wrong. That one can pip install mod_wsgi-express makes it easy to install and it is as easy to run as gunicorn.

Comment: That mod_wsgi-express has special development features such as automatic code reloading, pdb post mortem debugging, profiling, coverage analysis, request/response logging etc, all builtin, actually makes it a better choice than other main stream WSGI servers for development.